# Display product sale price in WooCommerce checkout issues

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, discount

I'm using this code snippet to display product sale prices at WooCommerce checkout:

```
function show_sale_price_at_checkout( $subtotal, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
    if ( ! $product ) {
        return $subtotal;
    }
    $regular_price = $sale_price = $suffix = '';
    if ( $product->is_taxable() ) {
        if ( 'excl' === WC()->cart->tax_display_cart ) {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price(), 'qty' => $quantity ) );
            $sale_price    = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price(), 'qty' => $quantity ) );
            if ( WC()->cart->prices_include_tax && WC()->cart->tax_total > 0 ) {
                $suffix .= ' ' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '';
            }
        } else {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price(), 'qty' => $quantity ) );
            $sale_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price(), 'qty' => $quantity ) );
            if ( ! WC()->cart->prices_include_tax && WC()->cart->tax_total > 0 ) {
                $suffix .= ' ' . WC()->countries->inc_tax_or_vat() . '';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $regular_price    = $product->get_price() * $quantity;
        $sale_price       = $product->get_sale_price() * $quantity;
    }
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && ! empty( $sale_price ) ) {
        $price = wc_format_sale_price(
                     wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price(), 'qty' => $quantity ) ),
                     wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'qty' => $quantity ) )
                 ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    } else {
        $price = wc_price( $regular_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
   
    $price = $price . $suffix;
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'show_sale_price_at_checkout', 10, 3 );
```

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/xLB60Px

However, there's **3** issues:

**1.** I'm unable to target the sale price individually with custom CSS. Is there a way to give the sale price a CSS class?

**2.** I can not change the color of the sale price properly. Setting the color to `#000000` does not result into pure black, it stays grey. So I thought the sale price is a bit transparent but adding `opacity: 1;` did not help, it stays grey. I can not increase the opacity, only decrease it. I'm confused.

**3.** When the checkout page is loading it shows this ugly long message next to the products that have no sale price: https://ibb.co/PzJztck What does it mean and how to get rid of it?

Could someone please help resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you check if the product is taxable and if the price must be VAT excluded or VAT included. **This check is already done in the WooCommerce function** `wc_get_price_to_display`: [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-product-functions.html#source-view.1078) the documentation.

So you could optimize it like this:

```
// shows the product price on sale (if any) in the checkout table
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'show_sale_price_at_checkout', 10, 3 );
function show_sale_price_at_checkout( $subtotal, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    
    // gets the product object
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    // get the quantity of the product in the cart
    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

    // check if the object exists
    if ( ! $product ) {
        return $subtotal;
    }

    // check if the product is on sale
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && ! empty( $product->get_sale_price() ) ) {
        // shows sale price and regular price       
        $price = wc_format_sale_price (
            // regular price
            wc_get_price_to_display(
                $product, array(
                    'price' => $product->get_regular_price(),
                    'qty' => $quantity
                    )
                ),
            // sale price
            wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array (
                'price' => $product->get_sale_price(),
                'qty' => $quantity
                )
            )
        ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    } else {
        // shows regular price
        $price = wc_price (
            // regular price
            wc_get_price_to_display(
                $product, array (
                    'price' => $product->get_regular_price(),
                    'qty' => $quantity
                )
            )
        ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
   
    return $price;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Regarding the 3 issues I will answer you by points:

1. You can use the `ins` element as a selector for the price on sale. For example: `tr.cart_item ins { ... }`
2. The previous point should resolve this point. In case it doesn't work, it could depend on the specificity of another previously declared selector. In this case you have two options:

   - find the CSS rule that has already been declared and modify it
   - add **`!important`** to the end of the new CSS rule *(It would be preferable to avoid it)*
3. The function I posted should fix this error.